# How can I pass custom data to my mocha tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, mocha.js, saucelabs

We are using [sauce labs](http://saucelabs.com) to do cross-platform/cross-browser testing.

You can find my test suite in this gist (to save room in this question): https://gist.github.com/chevex/397a5a18a1a386897b41

The problem is that the only way I could figure out how to pass custom data to the test suite is [via an environment variable](https://gist.github.com/chevex/397a5a18a1a386897b41#file-sauce-tests-js-L35). Because of this, when my gulp task tries to run the test suite against multiple targets in parallel, they all end up running against the same target since the loop is done iterating and `process.env.SAUCE_TARGET` is set to the final value before the first suite even runs.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpMocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var mergeStream = require('merge-stream');
gulp.task('sauce-tests', function () {
  var targets = ['chrome', 'firefox', 'internet explorer'];
  var streams = targets.map(function (target) {
    process.env.SAUCE_TARGET = target;
    return gulp.src('./test/sauce-tests.js', {read:false})
      .pipe(gulpMocha({ reporter: 'spec' });
  });
  return mergeStream.apply(null, streams);
});
```

The closure provided by `forEach` doesn't help because it's setting an essentially global value (`process.env.SAUCE_TARGET`) on each iteration.

Is there a better way to pass the `SAUCE_TARGET` to my test suite so that I can run multiple test suites in parallel with different target values?

I can get it working if I run all the tests synchronously but that takes far longer than I want it to. The only thing preventing parallelism is the fact that I can't pass encapsulated values to my mocha suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run tests in several browsers in parallel using [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/child_process.html) module.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function runMochaTests(browser) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       var env = {SAUCE_TARGET: browser};
       exec('./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter spec', {env: env}, function(err) {
          if(err !== null) {
              return reject(err);
          }
          return resolve();
       });
   });
}
```

It creates child process with test. Current browser will be availabe as `process.env.SAUCE_TARGET`.

Then you can use this function in gulp task to run tests in different browsers.

```
gulp.task('tests', function() {
    return Promise.all(['chrome', 'firefox', 'internet explorer'].map(function(browser) {
        return runMochaTests(browsers);
    }));
});
```

Here is used Promises because `gulp` can accept them as a task result and will wait until tests will be finished in all browsers.

Also you can add here some syntax sugar like [denodeify](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/denodeify) to make work with `exec` a bit shorter.

Comment: Do you know why I would be getting a `command not recognized: mocha` error with this? I can run mocha from the command line just fine, but when it tries to run from this child process it can't find the command.

Comment: That means that you don't have global `mocha`. Updated the answer, now it searches in `node_modules` folder

Comment: Ah but I do have global mocha, and I also already tried specifying the local path. It says there is no such file, even though when I navigate there manually it's there. I even tried `path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'mocha')`. It's definitely in there but for some reason the child process doesn't find it. I definitely have global mocha too, and I can run it manually just fine.

Comment: I can run commands like "help" but it just will not find mocha, not even with the fully qualified path specified. Google is no help. Very strange.

Comment: I've tried adding `process.env.PATH` to the `env` we give to the child process. Didn't help. I've also tried `var env = _.extend({}, process.env, { SAUCE_TARGET: target });` I even manually started `/bin/sh` (what exec appears to launch) and running `mocha` from there and it worked :/

Comment: Okay, it was because there was a bug in the test file causing it to have a non-zero exit code which was causing the promise to be rejected. Not sure why it was saying command not found, but fixing the tests fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting it in between pipes, specifically with the flush function:

```
  var through = require('through2');

  var setTarget = function (target) {
      return through.obj(
          function (chunk, enc, cb) { cb(null, chunk) },
          function (cb) { // flush function 
              process.env.SAUCE_TARGET = target;
              cb();
          }
      );
  }
  var streams = targets.map(function (target) {
    return gulp.src('./test/sauce-tests.js', {read:false})
      .pipe(setTarget(target))
      .pipe(gulpMocha({ reporter: 'spec', globals: [target] });
  });
```

Comment: This appears to have the same problem. All the tests are running against "internet explorer" (the last item in the target list).